# intersecting data structure

Tags: c++, memory

I have the following struct definitions:

```
struct vec { // 2-dim vector
    long d[2];
};
struct lineSegment { // a 2D-LineSegment with start/end points A, B
    vec A, B;
};
struct polygon { // a 2D-Polygon
    vec *points;
    polygon(unsigned int points) {
        vec = new vec[points];
    }
    polygon() {}
    ~polygon() { delete[] vec; }
};
```

My task is to write a method isPointInside(const vec &A, const polygon &P) that determines, if a given point A is inside a given polygon P or not.

**My implementation**
First my method creates a line segment L starting at A and ending at a point B, that is definitely outside the polygon. Second, it counts all the borders of the polygon that intersect with the line segment L. The given point A is exactly then inside the given polygon P, iff the counted borders of the polygon P are odd.

The method I use to find out, if two line segments do intersect has the following function declaration:

```
bool intersect(const line&, const line&);
```

The polygon is an array of all the corner points that define the polygon. A polygon P with n corner points

```
P = (P1, P2, ..., PN)
```

has the following borders :

```
(P1, P2), (P2, P3), ..., (P(N-1), PN), (PN, P1)
```

To iterate over all borders, I would like to use a 'const lineSegment'-pointer polyBorder, that is pointing inside the polygon.points array (that is of type vec) and that will be increased by sizeof(vec) after every iteration.

In each iteration (except the nth iteration) I want to call

```
intersect(L, *polyBorder);
```

**The Question**
Does this iteration work with any c/c++ compiler, or do some compiler store additional data for vec and lineSegment, such that this approach does not work for these?

Meaning, is this usage of pointers, well defined in the c/c++ standards or is this implementation specific?


// edit
Some exemple code (not tested and probably not working!):

```
polygon test(4);
// initialise the points in test.points

const lineSegment *polyBorder = reinterpret_cast<lineSegment*>((const void*)test.points); // first line
// do something

polyBorder = reinterpret_cast<const lineSegment*>(((const void*)polyBorder)+sizeof(vec)); // second line
// do something

polyBorder = reinterpret_cast<const lineSegment*>(((const void*)polyBorder)+sizeof(vec)); // third line
// do something
```

Comment: i suggest you to use standard STL containers (e.g. `std::vector`) and algorithms for iterating over containers, rather than raw pointers and manual allocation/deallocation

Comment: This method breaks down if your line passes through one or more vertices of the polygon. Just sayin'.

Comment: Don't describe code, show it.

Comment: @n.m.: This method does not break, read this for more: h ttp://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Comment: @n.m.: I can not show it, because it is not written yet (except the intersect method for lines). But that is beside the point, I have written down the implementation idea, to show you the motivation I have to missuse the pointer polyBorder. When I had not done that, most people here would just have said, don't do it like that.

Comment: @AndyProwl: look at the comment I made under the first answer.

I want to use the pointer like that, so I can use two neighboring points as lines. When I had used the vector class of the stl, it would not be possible to do that.

Comment: @user1861174: If understand you want to do that, I just don't think it's a good abstraction. You are relying on the memory contiguity of your objects to confer them a conceptual meaning (two contiguous points = 1 line). Personally I would not do that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. Are you asking whether `sizeof(vec)` includes the additional data that the compiler includes? Yes, it does. However, you would only increment by `sizeof(vec)` if your pointer is of type `char*`. When a pointer is of type `type*`, arithmetic operations on the pointer treat it as pointing to an array of `type` elements, and operate on whole elements. So you don't need to use `sizeof`.

UPDATE:

Now that I've seen your question edit, I think I understand it better. The basic question is:

Given an array:

```
T* array[N]
```

and a structure type:

```
struct S {
  T A, B;
};
```

can you use an `S*` pointer to access a pair of sequential elements in the array?

I think this should work. However, you shouldn't use the `sizeof` technique to generate the pointers, you should use normal pointer arithmetic with casts directly between the types:

```
const lineSegment *polyBorder = (lineSegment*)test.points; // first line
polyBorder = (lineSegment*)(((vec*)polyBorder))+1); // second line
polyBorder = (lineSegment*)(((vec*)polyBorder))+1); // third line
```

This makes the type-punning clear, and takes advantage of the way C/C++ do pointer arithmetic, automatically multiplying by the size of the element behind the scenes.

Comment: look closer on the pointer type; polyBorder is of type const lineSegment* (sizeof(lineSegment) min 2*sizeof(vec)) polygon.points is of type vec*. polyBorder is missused to access a vec-Array, so I can treat two neighbored points as a segment line. (I do this, so I do not have to create n segment lines for the polygon borders for use with intersect(...))

Comment: Please add the actual declarations to your question, and show the code that you're asking about. I'm having trouble understanding you from descriptions instead of actual code.

Comment: Doesn't matter, you should not add `sizeof(vec)` to a `vec*` anyway. Remember that `a[i] == *(a+i)`, by definition.